# not able to add CNAME record against domain registered in Azure app services

Tags: azure, dns, cname

i need to add a CNAME record against my domain purchased in Azure...the azure domains websites doesn't show any option to do that

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Create DNS zone in Azure "DNS zones". After it is created, it will already have 4 NS records
2. Go to "App Services" and add 4 name servers (from step 1.)
3. Add CNAME (or any other) records to your zone in "DNS Zones"

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/P22lgpY

Comment: [17:47, 19/10/2019] solanki rahul: I am able to see the NS records in the "DNS zone" page
[17:47, 19/10/2019] solanki rahul: However when i try to add a new CNAME record it doenst allow me to add a @ record.....it allowed me to add a subdomain record (pointed in screenshot)

Comment: i want www.solankrahul.com to point to audacity.westindia.cloudapp.azure.com

Comment: Your screenshot shows that you added `audacity`, just add `www` the same way: `www    CNAME    36000    audacity.westindia.cloudapp.azure.com`

Comment: issue resolved...thanks